# Create mysqli query parameters based on array contents

Tags: php

I am trying to build a query using the `LIKE` operator:

```
$args = array("this", "that", "other");

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblStockDet WHERE StockMastID LIKE '%{$args[0]}%'");
```

This works and returns only the results where `tblStockDet` contains the term "this". However, I may have several `LIKE` parameters in the array. So, in the above example, the `$args` array has 3 values. How do I automatically update the query to look like:

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblStockDet WHERE StockMastID LIKE '%{$args[0]}%' AND StockMastID LIKE '%{$args[1]}%' AND StockMastID LIKE '%{$args[2]}%'");
```

Comment: Easy answer is to use a loop -- do you have one that's not working and we can take a look at?

Comment: `implode("%' AND StockMastID LIKE '%", $args) . "%'"` ... not tested it but you get what I mean I hope - course, that won't sanitise your arguments so a loop might be better.

Comment: Maybe you may want an `OR` not an `AND` ...

Comment: @Alex No, it will always be `AND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to try a `foreach`:

```
$args = array("this", "that", "other");
$stmt = array('0'); // Prevent errors when $args is empty

foreach ($args as $arg) {
    $stmt[] = 'StockMastID LIKE %'.$arg.'%';
}

$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tblStockDet WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $stmt));
```